# Asymptotic location of the turning points of $\ddot x = -x-{\dot x}^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

Fix a solution $x(t)$ of the following ODE: $$\ddot x=-x-\dot {x}^3.$$

1. Does the energy $E(t) := x^2 + \dot x^2 $ decrease to zero as $t \to \infty$?
2. Denote by $x_1,x_2,\ldots $ the positive values of $x(t)$ for which $\dot x(t)=0$, ordered by time. Prove that the following limit exists: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_n^3}.$$

### Some Remarks

- To prove 1 it is enough to prove that $\dot x \to 0$, since then $x\to c$ and the ODE forces $c=0$.
- If we had $\dot x \not \to 0$ then $\dot x$ would have been bounded away from $0$ "a lot", so $\dot E=-\dot x ^4$ would decrease at a rate bounded from below, hence tend to zero. This is not yet a proof because $\dot x$ might only have spikes away from zero. Perhaps this will make its second derivative large and lead to a contradiction with the ODE?
- In the linearized equation the sequence $(x_n)$ is constant, and for $t\gg 0$ we expect the system to be very close to its linearization. The limit quantifies this.
- I [cross-posted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622604/asymptotic-frequency-of-nonlinear-oscillator-ddot-x-x-dot-x3-speed-cu) from the physics site.

Comment: The ODE in the question and in the title differ. Since in your linked post, you asked about $\ddot{x} = -x - \dot{x}^3$ you probably mean that one, right?

Comment: Good catch, fixed

Comment: A small remark: From $\dot x \to 0$ you cannot in general deduce that $x \to c$. (Consider $x(t)=\ln t$, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 1 is yes.

The ODE can be written as a system $\dot x = y$, $\dot y = -x - y^3$, and with $E=\frac12(x^2+y^2)$ we have $\dot E = - y^4 \le 0$, so $E$ is a weak Lyapunov function. The set where $\dot E=0$ is the $x$-axis, and it contains no complete trajectories except the origin. (Indeed, the vector field $(\dot x,\dot y)$ equals $(0,-x)$ when $y=0$, so the other trajectories intersect the $x$-axis orthogonally). Therefore LaSalle's theorem says that the origin is an asymptotically stable equilibrium; in fact, it's even globally asymptotically stable, since $E \to \infty$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \to \infty$. That is, all trajectories converge to the origin as $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: How do we promote the local asymptotic stability to a global convergence? Ostensibly outside a small neighborhood of $0$ the solution $(x,y)$ stays bounded away from both $0$ and $\infty$?

Comment: @Pachirisu: Note that $E=d^2/2$ where $d$ is the distance from the origin. And $E$ is strictly decreasing to zero along any trajectory, hence so is $d$. (The point of the Lyapunov/LaSalle theory is that you don't only get stability, you also get a *region* of stability. In this case, all of $\mathbf{R}^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

As found in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/622604/asymptotic-frequency-of-nonlinear-oscillator, the main trend of the solution for smaller amplitudes is, starting from $x(t_n)=x_n>0$, $y(t_n)=\dot x(t_n)=0$, $y=\dot x$,
$$
x(t)\approx \frac{x_n\cos(t-t_n)}{\sqrt{1+\frac34x_n^2(t-t_n)}},
\\
y(t)\approx \frac{x_n\sin(t-t_n)}{\sqrt{1+\frac34x_n^2(t-t_n)}}.
$$
Thus the energy is falling, the points $x_n$ are $2\pi$ apart in time and the limit does indeed exist with value $\frac34\pi$.